# Find in Files Not available in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

So this is probably a dumb question, but on one of my dev machines "Find in Files" does not exist under the edit menu.  All that exists is 'Quick Find' & 'Quick Replace'.  Can't find anything online about hiding or showing this menu option, and its always just been there on other installs, so I'm stumped.

Note: This is under Visual Studio 2005 AND 2008 and local only to this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Put it back with Tools + Customize.  Select Edit, then click and drag "Find in Files" to the menu.

Tools + Import and Export, Reset is the sledgehammer solution.